# Unable to get correct json values from jersey response

Tags: java, json, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am fetching values from database and I have a webservice which returns a list of values fetched from database which I am sending it to front-end view layer on request from angular like a webservice call

The problem is I am getting incorrect json values. It getting keys instead of values. When I see it in chrome console the json is like:

```
{"jobName":"NASA Scientist",
"jobPrimarySkill":null,
"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE",
"jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP",         // keyname instead of value (Incorrect values)
"jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION", // keyname instead of value (Incorrect values)
"jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS",   // keyname instead of value (Incorrect values)
"jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE",           // keyname instead of value (Incorrect values)
"jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY",      // keyname instead of value (Incorrect values)
"jobPostedBy":null}
```

I have my back end code like this:

```
@Path("/FetchJobSummary")
public class FetchJobSummaryService {

FetchJobSummaryDAO dao = new FetchJobSummaryDAO();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List fetch() {

    System.out.println(dao.getJobSummaries()); 
    // prints object [com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@6d90d6c5, 
        com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@6d90d6c5, 
        com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@6d90d6c5,....

    return dao.getJobSummaries();
    }
}
```

DAO class:

```
public class FetchJobSummaryDAO {

public List getJobSummaries() {

JobSummaries jobSummaries = new JobSummaries();
List<JobSummaries> jobSummaryList = new ArrayList<JobSummaries>();

try {
    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();

    String query = "select JOB_NAME,JOB_DESCRIPTION,JOB_ROLE,JOB_PRIMARY_SKILL,JOB_DESIGNATION,JOB_EXP,JOB_SAL_RANGE, JOB_POSTEDBY from TBL_JOBPOSTING";

    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) {
        jobSummaries.setJobName(rs.getString("JOB_NAME"));
        jobSummaries.setJobDescription("JOB_DESCRIPTION");
        jobSummaries.setJobRole("JOB_ROLE");
        jobSummaries.setJobPrimarySkill(rs.getString("JOB_PRIMARY_SKILL"));
        jobSummaries.setJobDesignation("JOB_DESIGNATION");
        jobSummaries.setJobExp("JOB_EXP");
        jobSummaries.setJobSalaryRange("JOB_SAL_RANGE");
        jobSummaries.setJobPostedBy("JOB_POSTEDBY");
        jobSummaryList.add(jobSummaries);

        for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
            if (i > 1) {
               System.out.print(",  ");
            }
            String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
            System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + " " + columnValue); //Prints correct values
        }
        }

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FetchJobSummaryDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return jobSummaryList;
}
```

I am sure its the problem somewhere in java than in frontend but not to figure out what is wrong

Comment: You need to get the data from the ResultSet like you are with job name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have

```
jobSummaries.setJobRole("JOB_ROLE");
```

instead of

```
jobSummaries.setJobRole(rs.getString("JOB_ROLE"));
```

so you should have

```
    jobSummaries.setJobName(rs.getString("JOB_NAME"));
    jobSummaries.setJobDescription(rs.getString("JOB_DESCRIPTION"));
    jobSummaries.setJobRole(rs.getString("JOB_ROLE"));
    jobSummaries.setJobPrimarySkill(rs.getString("JOB_PRIMARY_SKILL"));
    jobSummaries.setJobDesignation(rs.getString("JOB_DESIGNATION"));
    jobSummaries.setJobExp(rs.getString("JOB_EXP"));
    jobSummaries.setJobSalaryRange(rs.getString("JOB_SAL_RANGE"));
    jobSummaries.setJobPostedBy(rs.getString("JOB_POSTEDBY"));
    jobSummaryList.add(jobSummaries);
```

Comment: glad to help :) happens to the best of us!

Comment: Thank you. Just found out one more issue about the same question. Thinking shall I create a new question? The new issue is its printing only first set of json object in the front end but actually I have 6 different json object like the one in the question

Comment: looks like jobSummaryList only has 1 value. are you sure you are getting all the rows in reslutset?

Comment: Yes I am able to print it in `System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + " " + columnValue);'`in the DAO class as in the question, but I doubt that in webservice class when I do `return dao.getJobSummaries();` //not sure its getting all values or not

Comment: I figured it out. The actuall problem is in `dao.getJobSummaries();` which is printing same hash codes so I guess its getting only one value

Comment: Posted a new question about the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546976/unable-to-get-all-values-of-json

Answer (score 1):

As you are taking "JOB_PRIMARY_SKILL" from result set using rs.getString, try 
rs.getString("JOB_DESIGNATION"), maybe you are missing out that.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is from here :`

```
while (rs.next()) {
    jobSummaries.setJobName(rs.getString("JOB_NAME"));
    jobSummaries.setJobDescription("JOB_DESCRIPTION");
    jobSummaries.setJobRole("JOB_ROLE");
    jobSummaries.setJobPrimarySkill(rs.getString("JOB_PRIMARY_SKILL"));
    jobSummaries.setJobDesignation("JOB_DESIGNATION");
    jobSummaries.setJobExp("JOB_EXP");
    jobSummaries.setJobSalaryRange("JOB_SAL_RANGE");
    jobSummaries.setJobPostedBy("JOB_POSTEDBY");
    jobSummaryList.add(jobSummaries);
```

it should be :

```
` while (rs.next()) {
    jobSummaries.setJobName(rs.getString("JOB_NAME"));
    jobSummaries.setJobDescription(rs.getString("JOB_DESCRIPTION"));
    jobSummaries.setJobRole(rs.getString("JOB_ROLE"));
    jobSummaries.setJobPrimarySkill(rs.getString("JOB_PRIMARY_SKILL"));
    jobSummaries.setJobDesignation(rs.getString("JOB_DESIGNATION"));
    jobSummaries.setJobExp(rs.getString("JOB_EXP"));
    jobSummaries.setJobSalaryRange(rs.getString("JOB_SAL_RANGE"));
    jobSummaries.setJobPostedBy(rs.getString("JOB_POSTEDBY"));
    jobSummaryList.add(jobSummaries);
```

`