# unable to get all values of json

Tags: java, json, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am trying to return values fetched from database to frontend view using rest webservice but the problem is its returning only the one line(first line) of json values

I have json like this:

```
{"jobName":"NASA Scientist","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"Sample 2","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
{"jobName":"NASA Scientist","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
{"jobName":"Web developer","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"XYZ 123","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
{"jobName":"Web developer","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
{"jobName":"Programmer","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
{"jobName":"Programmer","jobPrimarySkill":null,"jobRole":"JOB_ROLE","jobDesignation":"JOB_EXP","jobDescription":"JOB_DESCRIPTION","jobSalaryRange":"JOB_POSITIONS","jobExp":"JOB_SAL_RANGE","jobPositions":"JOB_POSTEDBY","jobPostedBy":null}
```

Its returning only first line of json values to the front end rather than all of them. I am adding the fetched values from database to `List` and exposing it in webservice like this:

```
public class FetchJobSummaryDAO {

public List getJobSummaries() {

JobSummaries jobSummaries = new JobSummaries();
List<JobSummaries> jobSummaryList = new ArrayList<JobSummaries>();

try {
    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();

    String query = "select JOB_NAME,JOB_DESCRIPTION,JOB_ROLE,JOB_PRIMARY_SKILL,JOB_DESIGNATION,JOB_EXP,JOB_SAL_RANGE, JOB_POSTEDBY from TBL_JOBPOSTING";

    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) {
        jobSummaries.setJobName(rs.getString("JOB_NAME"));
        jobSummaries.setJobDescription(rs.getString("JOB_DESCRIPTION"));
        jobSummaries.setJobRole(rs.getString("JOB_ROLE"));
        jobSummaries.setJobPrimarySkill(rs.getString("JOB_PRIMARY_SKILL"));
        jobSummaries.setJobDesignation(rs.getString("JOB_DESIGNATION"));
        jobSummaries.setJobExp(rs.getString("JOB_EXP"));
        jobSummaries.setJobSalaryRange(rs.getString("JOB_SAL_RANGE"));
        jobSummaries.setJobPostedBy(rs.getString("JOB_POSTEDBY"));
        jobSummaryList.add(jobSummaries);

        for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
            if (i > 1) {
                System.out.print(",  ");
            }
            String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
            System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + " " + columnValue);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FetchJobSummaryDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return jobSummaryList;
}
```

webservice:

```
@Path("/FetchJobSummary")
public class FetchJobSummaryService {
FetchJobSummaryDAO dao = new FetchJobSummaryDAO();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<JobSummaries> fetch() {
    List js = dao.getJobSummaries();
    for(int i=0; i< js.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(js); //prints values with same hashcode
    }
    return dao.getJobSummaries();
    }
}
```

When I print the list, it prints values with same hashcode so I guess its getting only one value of json

```
[com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809]
[com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809]
[com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809]
[com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809]
[com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809]
[com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809, com.RTH.WebServices.JobSummaries@691c5809]
```

Comment: This is very basic Java. Look where you create the JobSummaries and when you are adding it to the list. You are using the same instance. You need to create a new one for each row of data

Comment: @peeskillet you are right.. the list contains only one element.. basic concept

Answer (score 2):

Change like this

```
public class FetchJobSummaryDAO {

     public List getJobSummaries() {

     JobSummaries jobSummaries = null;
     List<JobSummaries> jobSummaryList = new ArrayList<JobSummaries>();

  try {

    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();

String query = "select JOB_NAME,JOB_DESCRIPTION,JOB_ROLE,JOB_PRIMARY_SKILL,JOB_DESIGNATION,JOB_EXP,JOB_SAL_RANGE, JOB_POSTEDBY from TBL_JOBPOSTING";

PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while (rs.next()) {
    jobSummaries =  new JobSummaries()
    jobSummaries.setJobName(rs.getString("JOB_NAME"));
    jobSummaries.setJobDescription(rs.getString("JOB_DESCRIPTION"));
    jobSummaries.setJobRole(rs.getString("JOB_ROLE"));
   jobSummaries.setJobPrimarySkill(rs.getString("JOB_PRIMARY_SKILL"));
    jobSummaries.setJobDesignation(rs.getString("JOB_DESIGNATION"));
    jobSummaries.setJobExp(rs.getString("JOB_EXP"));
    jobSummaries.setJobSalaryRange(rs.getString("JOB_SAL_RANGE"));
    jobSummaries.setJobPostedBy(rs.getString("JOB_POSTEDBY"));
    jobSummaryList.add(jobSummaries);

    for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
        if (i > 1) {
            System.out.print(",  ");
        }
        String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
        System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + " " + columnValue);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

 } catch (SQLException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(FetchJobSummaryDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,               null, ex);
   }
  return jobSummaryList;
```

}

Comment: Thanks Anoop LL It should work but just wondering that for each result set row it will create a new instance. Isn't this a bad oo approach. Is there any better for me to learn and achieve the same?

Comment: @kittu It should create a new instance then only we can save the reference in list other-ways how will we store these objects in list?? This is not a bad approach this is the best approach..

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues:
1) You need to create a new instance each time you loop in getJobSummaries
2) You need to print out each row not the list each time

the issue is here:

```
List js = dao.getJobSummaries();
    for(int i=0; i< js.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(js); //prints the whole list every time
    }
```

You're printing out the list every time.  I think you want to get the items in the list - like:

```
List js = dao.getJobSummaries();
for (Object j : js) {
        System.out.println(j); //prints each item in the list
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. Just wondering that for each result set row it will create a new instance. Isn't this a bad oo approach. Is there any better for me to learn and achieve the same?